# Outlook pst problem

Tags: exchange, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, pst

I've used outlook pst files in the past with great success.  a few weeks ago I exported about 2 years worth of email into a pst file.  size is around 1.5 gb.  when i try ti import that pst back into my outlook it says its not a pst file.  I've tried to repair it using pstscan and it repairs errors and will even mount it in Outlook but Outlook cant see any emails, like its an empty pst file.  Is there any other way to recover my emails besides loading up backupexec and recovering my mailbox before i made the pst?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-unicode PST has a limit of 2GB, so you are definitely inside of that as far as limits go. If scanpst was unable to recover the file, you will need to look into 3rd party tools. I've used the [Recovery for Outlook](http://www.officerecovery.com/outlook/) in the past with near 100% success.

Answer (score 0):

There are applications that state that they can recover PST files but most cost...

If  it is possible to restore from a backup then i would suggest that myself as any repair may still be missing data.